# Vuetify3- Open tooltip on-click only

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I've seen some examples of a button to copy data with a tooltip using vuetify2.

Out project is currently using vuetify3 version..

I've followed vuetify docs and here is my current component code:

```html
<template>
  <VTooltip :model-value="data.showTooltip">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
      <VBtn
        icon
        :color="properties.buttonColor"
        :size="properties.size"
        :elevation="elevation"
        @click="copyData"
        v-on:hover="data.showTooltip = false"
        v-bind="props"
      >
        <VIcon>mdi-content-copy</VIcon>
      </VBtn>
    </template>
    Copied to clipboard
  </VTooltip>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
export interface CopyButtonProps {
  size?: string;
  elevation?: number | undefined;
  data: string;
  tooltipLocation?: string | undefined;
  tooltipTimeoutMs?: number;
  buttonColor?: string;
}
export interface CopyButtonData {
  showTooltip: boolean;
}
const properties = withDefaults(defineProps<CopyButtonProps>(), {
  size: "small",
  elevation: 1,
  tooltipLocation: "end",
  buttonColor: "white transparent",
  tooltipTimeoutMs: 1000,
});
const data = reactive<CopyButtonData>({
  showTooltip: false,
});
function showTooltip() {
  data.showTooltip = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    data.showTooltip = false;
  }, properties.tooltipTimeoutMs);
}
async function copyData(isTooltipActive: boolean) {
  if (!properties.data) return;
  await navigator.clipboard.writeText(properties.data);
  showTooltip();
  return true;
}
</script>
```

The code above makes the tooltip opens on click, but is also opening on hover, and  I don't want this behavior. Do you have any suggestions to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:open-on-hover="false"`

Comment: thaaanks a lot, i didn't find any docs about it, not in version 3

Comment: https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tooltip/#props-open-on-hover

Comment: It existed in v2 as well https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tooltip/#props-open-on-hover